# Drag Slick JS and content changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I create slider and content using slick js.
Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3 class="none">2</h3></div>
    <div><h3 class="none">3</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">this is first content</div>
  <div class="other">this is second content</div>
</div>
```

and my JS

```
$(".slick-dots").click(function(){
  if(!$(".slick-slide.slick-current").children().hasClass("none")){
    $(".content").show();
    $(".other").hide();
  } else {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".other").show();
}
var isDragging = false;
$(".slick-slide")
.mousedown(function() {
  isDragging = false;
})
.mousemove(function() {
  isDragging = true;
})
.mouseup(function() {
  var wasDragging = isDragging;
  isDragging = false;
  if (wasDragging || !wasDragging) {
    $(".other").show();
  }
})
;
```

I hope to use drag slide function like click button in slick dots.
Here is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/e5bxsz3o/11/
Anybody help? Thank you

Comment: Can you clear what you want?

Comment: when I drag from <h3 class="none">2</h3> to <h3>1</h3> is different. And I hope like click slick-dots

Comment: Please check this, i think you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/pre10tf8/2/